# How does the computer AI decide who to surrender to?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-2

I'm pretty deep into my latest game of Galactic Civilizations 2: Twilight of the Arnor, and major races are starting to drop out of the game.  Except, in Gal Civ 2 instead of sticking around until they are totally eliminated, the major races will surrender to a friendly civilization, deeding their planets over to that friendly civilization.

How does the AI determine who to surrender to, and is there some way to game the system?  Daddy wants more free planets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question would be best answered by the devs themselves, I'll offer my observation.

The main decision seems to be the Alliance factor. In a game I just finished, the Altarians after being whupped up by the Yors, decided to surrender their (quite sizable) territory to my Krynn nation. They were allied with me, but not allied with others. Even though I was actually in a quasi-battle for influence with the Altarians.

The second main factor seems to be the Good/Evil alignment. In the same game I had just finished (see above), my Krynn (Neutral) had an alliance with Korath (Evil). When Korath surrendered (due to badly-going war against Drath), they chose to bequeath their leftover planets to their *other* ally, the Yor Collective (Evil).

Side note: It goes without saying that I leveraged this factor extensively: having been dragged into war with Yor by my ally the Altarians (which then proceeded to bow out of the galaxy leaving me with the loose ends), I can then pluck the (previously) Korath planets without having to break a treaty. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recently played a game as Terrans with my diplomacy and influence beefed up very high. I was neutral alignment but an evil AI that I wasn't even allied with surrendered both his planets to me. I fought him earlier, weakened him, then accepted his treaty. Then I embargoed him, so it's not like he had much reason to like me... except that everyone else kept on attacking him, so he hated them even more than me. In the end he surrendered to me rather than them, so I have to assume that high diplomacy skills and/or influence ratings have an impact.

Answer (score -1):

I am unsure of the first and main question on who it goes to. I am unsure if it is random, the strongest player, split evenly, etc.  But I have had it happen.  I also have had it split (which I found is good to know).

To your 2nd question of gaming the system: YES, Influence! Before their surrender when you see your ally start to take a beating trade with them as much as possible for influence/power.  Do this to EVERYONE!  It is really easy to accumulate a lot of points which makes you a larger power in the galactic council (gives you more voting power).  The AI loves to trade planets for Influence power/money/tech.  Many have argued it to be too "gamey" as in gaming of the system established.

To get the desired outcome tinker with your diplomatic approach and you will get to what I am talking about.